# How do I fix a "initial content not found" error?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, debugging, air, flash-builder

Using Flash Builder 4.6 on some code from a client.  Clicked on debug (also tried run) and received this error:

```
Process terminated unexpectedly.

initial content not found

Launch command details:  "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.6.0
\bin\adl.exe" -runtime "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.6.0
\runtimes\air\win" -profile mobileDevice -screensize 640x920:640x960 -XscreenDPI 326 -
XversionPlatform IOS "C:\Users\tstiffler\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\TP\bin-debug\TP-
app.xml" "C:\Users\tstiffler\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\TP\bin-debug"
```

How do I fix this?  Please be as detailed as you can as I've never used Flash Builder before.  Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

I had Main-app.xml file, in it I changed the following line

```
<content>[This value will be overwritten by Flash Builder in the output app.xml]</content>
```

to

```
<content>{yourAppName}.swf</content>
```

and initial content problem was solved.

Comment: If you're using something like FlashDevelop, make sure the name that you're outputting your SWF under matches what's here

Answer (score 1):

I went to the app descriptor XML file just like **hrehman**, but mine just had the SWF file that I've been using - *MyGame-iOS.swf* - and I tried changing this to any other name (*MyGame.swf*), then tried building and running and it worked fine.

Not the best solution, but just in case someone goes to do what **hrehman** did, and doesn't see the square-bracketed message and is still stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this when my SWF-metadata was invalid. The swf was not even listed in the package content of my project.
So, in short, be sure your swf-metadata is valid. I changed the value of backgroundColor from this (which works):

```
    [SWF(frameRate="60", width="480", height="800", backgroundColor="#000000")]
```

to

```
    [SWF(frameRate="60", width="480", height="800", backgroundColor="#0x0")]
```

The hash sign in backgroundColor should not have been there, and so I experienced the Flash Builder initial content error. Changing the second line to:

```
    [SWF(frameRate="60", width="480", height="800", backgroundColor="0x0")]
```

And my swf was once again included in the package.

Answer (score 0):

For me the opening the Main-app.xml file, change something insignificant and saving it again, worked. Maybe something to do with caching of build files or something?
I must say, this was in 4.7 though.

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens after we change the location of the application's main `mxml` file. What fixes it for me is to ensure that `YourApplication-app.xml` and `YourApplication.mxml` are *both* located in `/src` folder. After that, rebuild the project should work.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was restoring my project's "bin-debug" folder (the directory where my compiled application is output) to a previous revision. Personally, I'm running Windows 7, so I just used the OS' revision control.

The other suggestions on this thread didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

@hrehma's answer is right.
And further, if you're using a wrong namespace, compiler won't get the xml tag. This happens when you change your AIR SDK version.

- Correct the *content* tag (like @hrehma said)
- Correct the *namespace* in application.xml root.

*For example if you're using AIR SDK 16:*

change

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/15.0">
```

to

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/16.0">
```

Hope this may help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is a bit of a catch-all and is very unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

This happen to me yesterday, I fixed it by creating a new project and copying everything in it except the main constructor as3 file. Then I copied the variables and functions from the old( broke ) main file and pasted them in the new one.

I think the reason is that the main class gets file gets corrupted somehow and flash builder cannot read it even though it looks fine in the editor.