# AIR 4.0 Flash Builder Error: Initial Content Not Found

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, builder

I am making a starling app in flash builder 4.7 in actionscript 3 as mobile actionscript project. Everything was going fine until I decided that I wanted to change the name of the project and the name of the document class. Then I started getting the error message. I have already looked at a few posts, tried what they suggested, and still get the error when I try to debug it.

Error Message:

Process terminated without establishing connection to debugger.

initial content not found

Launch command details:  "/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/eclipse/plugins/com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722/AIRSDK/bin/adl" -runtime "/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/eclipse/plugins/com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722/AIRSDK/runtimes/air/mac" -profile mobileDevice -screensize 640x1116:640x1136 -XscreenDPI 326 -XversionPlatform IOS /Users/bobolicious3000/Documents/Aclown/RuMenusDMT/bin-debug/HelloDMT2-app.xml /Users/bobolicious3000/Documents/Aclown/RuMenusDMT/bin-debug

What I have tried already:

- Changing the  parameter in the xml descriptor file:
  It was:

> `[This value will be overwritten by Flash Builder in the output app.xml]`

and I changed it to a lot of things including:

```
<content>RuMenusDMT.swf</content>
```

Nothing worked.

- Changing the header of the xml file.

I am use AIR 4.0 swc, and the xml file header looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/4.0">
```

- Cleaning the project

I normally like flash builder, but this is really giving me a hard time.

Comment: Alright, if no one has any ideas I may need to just make a new project...

Comment: Ok fine. I am making a new project. But someone from Adobe should really look into this because you really should be able to change project names without the entire thing crashing down...

Comment: See related post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475655/how-do-i-fix-a-initial-content-not-found-error

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was restoring my project's "bin-debug" folder (the directory where my compiled application is output) to a previous revision. Personally, I'm running Windows 7, so I just used the OS' revision control.