# Flash Builder Process terminated unexpectedly. error while loading initial content

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

[image]

I get a message as above trying to copy an SWF from an AIR app to run on a mobile device when building.

I've tried all the steps Jim Lynch lists here [AIR 4.0 Flash Builder Error: Initial Content Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367898/air-4-0-flash-builder-error-initial-content-not-found) but to no avail

Any advice appreciated

Answer (score 0):

SaachiTech kindly pointed out that you can compile Android Apps directly from flash itself in publish settings, which achieved what I wanted to accomplish